# How to force update of network account cached credentials on OSX

Tags: macos, passwords

My work laptop is OSX and uses a network account for authentication.  I have to change my network password every 90 days.  I have just changed it, but my laptop has not updated the account login for 2 password changes now, so to login to the machine I have to enter my password from 4 months ago, but for everything else on the network I have to enter the current password (and have updated the keychain as such.)

I can supposedly update the account on the mac if I plug it in to a land line, but I don't have one at my desk.  How can I force my macbook to update the cached credentials for the user account without having to plugin to a landline?

Comment: I assume the laptop is actually connected to the network?

Comment: Yes, connected wirelessly to the network using the newest AD password.

Answer (score 2):

I've blogged about that at http://andreas.heigl.org/2013/03/26/update-cached-user-information-from-apples-opendirectory/.

It basically boils down to "Remove the user from the internal storage while keeping the homedirectory and then creating it via a fresh login". As the mobile account is still available it will be detected at login and will not be overwritten.

**Do so at your own risk**

We've encountered this issue sporadically when changing the password via the user preferences while not connected to our OpenDirectory. Therefore the computer will change the password but it will not get reported to the OpenDirctory. Therefore all further changes of the password will not reach the OpenDirectory as the old password doesnt match the one stored in the Directory. We couldn't find another way of gettin the passords in sync again. But as I already pointed out: **use this information at your own risk! You might loose data.**

Comment: If I'm physically connected to the network then logout and back in it will update my cached credentials.  The problem comes with the fact that I don't want to climb under my desk to find the correct ethernet cable to plug into my laptop.  So this sounds like the hard way, but it may have to do with the differences between our environments.